# Magento Override Progess Block Template

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, template

I would like to override `shipping method` template of the progress block in `checkout` page. Below is the code I've tried but its not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<checkout_onepage_progress>
     <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

         <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
             <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
             <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shippingmethod.progress" template="newfolder/progress/shipping_method.phtml"></block>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_progress>
      <checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="newfolder/progress/shipping_method.phtml">
            <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method>
```

Comment: are you creating a module?

Comment: No Just modifying a template

Answer (score 0):

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml`
copy to your theme
`app/design/frontend/youpackage/theme/layout/checkout.xml` on line `386` change your template file

```
<checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml">
            <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method>
```